# Unity Linq to Sql DataClasses

Tags: sql, linq, unity-game-engine, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to add Linq-to-SQL data classes to Unity project but I get an error:

> Assets\Scripts\DataClasses1.designer.cs(46,65): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I need to use Linq-to-SQL in my Unity project.

When I add `System.Data.Linq.dll` and `System.Data.dll` to my `Plugins` folder, I get these errors:

> Loading assembly failed: "Assets/Plugins/System.Data.dll"
> Loading assembly failed: "Assets/Plugins/System.Data.Linq.dll"

Does anybody know how I can use Linq-to-SQL in my Unity project?

I already set Unity-> Player->Api Compatibility Level->.net 4.x but it does not solve the problem.

Comment: Linq to SQL is very old.  Are you sure you wouldn't prefer Entity Framework Core?

Comment: I cannot use Entity Framework Core in Unity Project Either. Assembly 'Assets/Plugins/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll' will not be loaded due to errors:
Unable to resolve reference 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions'. Is the assembly missing or incompatible with the current platform? I get more error

Comment: Which version v .NET Framework are you using in your project?